admission webhook "validation.istio.io" denied the request
We have multiple issues for Istio VS and issue for VS config for Istio.
We are trying to add below config for Ingress:
istio:
  virtualService:
    enabled: true
    timeout: 1m 
    port: 8080
    prefix: 
      - '/case360/api/caseDetails' 

But got the error for deployment:
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: admission webhook "validation.istio.io" denied the request: configuration is invalid: 2 errors occurred:
    * domain name "host 1" invalid (label "host 1" invalid)
    * domain name "host 2" invalid (label "host 2" invalid)

I am trying to deploy VS for Istio and it should work and it should reach by API endpoint.

Please share virtual service manifest.   The error denotes the domain name provided under hosts  in virtual service might be wrong
